# How to show message by messages from main class in UI window?

Tags: java, swing, swt, awt

Unfortunately I can't do step by step output in the main program window (object g).

### Part of main class:

```
/* Create a main window  of GUI*/  
    Gui g = new Gui();        
    g.showitself(); /*object is shown on the screen*/

    /*Check folder existing*/
    boolean inOutFilesFolderExists = (new File(vars.diskLetter+"//"+vars.ppmRootFolder+"//"+vars.inOutFilesFolder).exists());
         if (inOutFilesFolderExists)
            {
             System.out.println("Folder exists."); /*it is just for understanding if-operator works*/
             String textMessage = "\n"+"Folder " + vars.diskLetter+"//"+vars.ppmRootFolder+"//"+vars.inOutFilesFolder + "exists."+"\n" ; /*the message that I want to show in the main screen*/
             g.printmessage(logCurDateTime, textMessage); /*I am trying to show textMessage in the main GUI window by this method - g.printmessage  */
             }
         else
             { System.out.println("Folder doesn’t exists.");
            String textMessage = "Folder " + vars.diskLetter+"//"+vars.ppmRootFolder+"//"+vars.inOutFilesFolder + " doesn’t exist and will be created." ;
             g.printmessage(logCurDateTime, textMessage);
             new File(vars.diskLetter+"//"+vars.ppmRootFolder+"//"+vars.inOutFilesFolder).mkdirs();
             }
/** Now I am trying to create a new text message that should follow after previous text message */
            String textMessage = "Hello, Java Log.";
           // get to g object variables for showing 
            g.printmessage(logCurDateTime,  textMessage);
```

### GUI class:

```
        public class Gui {
                        Border solidBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 6);
                        Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 12);
                       //method which shows the main window of GUI
                        JFrame main_Window = new JFrame("PPM v.2.0");
                        public void showitself ()
                       {
                            main_Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                            main_Window.setSize(800, 400);
                            main_Window.setVisible(true);
                       }
                        /*This method should show messages from main class */
                        void printmessage (String logCurDateTime, String textMessage)
                       {
                       JLabel label = new JLabel("      " + logCurDateTime + " - " + textMessage +"\n");
                        main_Window.getContentPane().add(label);
                        }
        }
```

As result I receive GUI main screen only with the last message "Hello, Java Log.". 
As I understand it means than the previous message is rewritten by the next, but I need  a serial output of messages (message by message) like this:

> logCurDateTime  - Folder exists. (or Folder doesn’t exist and will be created.)
>
> logCurDateTime - "Hello, Java Log."

Also I am trying to recode (using `eclipse.swt` library) printmessage method as

```
void printmessage (String logCurDateTime, String textMessage)
             {

             JTextArea mainTextArea = new JTextArea();
             mainTextArea.append(logCurDateTime + textMessage +"/n");
             }
```

But it doesn’t help (no any message at all).

How to make a code which show messages from main class one by one?

Comment: Move the logic in main to a method, probably in a separate class.  Create an instance of the object containing the method, and call it using whatever parameters are supplied by the GUI.  (I may not understand the question, though.)

Comment: Andrew, the question is how to show message by message from main class in user interface window.

Comment: BTW - why is an SWT method being called from a Swing based GUI?

Comment: It was just attempt to solve the problem using SWT library. Оriginally i tried to use SWING.

Answer (score 4):

The `printmessage` method is creating a new instance of a `JTextArea` but never adding that instance to a container.  It seems the text area should be instantiated and added once in the constructor or `initComponents()` method.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the layout of the content pane is a BorderLayout. You could replace it by a GridLayout or a BoxLayout.

```
// a GridLayout
main_Window.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
// or a BoxLayout
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
main_Window.setContentPane(panel);
```

GridBagLayout is also a possible option.

Comment: +1 great catch.  I usually do not look at code snippets closely, instead preferring an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that I can wrap my compiler around.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody!
This class show message by message in the frame:

```
public class Gui {
    Border solidBorder = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.GRAY, 6);
    Font font = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, 12);


    JFrame main_Window = new JFrame("PPM v.2.0");
    JTextArea mainTextArea = new JTextArea(5, 200);

    public void showitself ()
    {

            main_Window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            main_Window.setSize(800, 400);
            main_Window.setVisible(true);
            main_Window.add(mainTextArea);


    }


    public void printMessage(final String textMessage) {
        if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {
            appendMessage(textMessage);
        } else {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    appendMessage(textMessage);
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void appendMessage(String message) {
        mainTextArea.append(message);
        mainTextArea.append("\n");
    }

}
```